# docker build is very slow even with simple commands

Tags: arm, docker

I'm building a docker image on my Raspberry Pi, which is of course takes some time. The problem here is that even very simple commands in the Dockerfile like setting an environment variable, using `chmod +x` on a single file or exposing port 80 take minutes to complete.

Here is an excerpt of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM resin/rpi-raspbian
MAINTAINER felixbr <mymail@redacted.com>

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get update && apt-get install -y python python-dev python-pip python-numpy python-scipy python-mysqldb mysql-server redis-server nginx dos2unix poppler-utils

COPY requirements.txt /app/

RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN cp /app/nginx-django.cfg /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN chmod +x /app/start.sh

ENV DOCKERIZED="true"

CMD ./start.sh

EXPOSE 80
```

Keep in mind this is using an `ARMv6` base image, so it can run on a Raspberry Pi and I'm using docker 1.5.0 built for the hypriot Raspberry Pi OS.

Is it copying the built layers for every command or why does each of the last few commands take minutes to complete?

Comment: Not going to help a lot, but you could merge all your RUN instructions into one line, which would be a bit more efficient.

Comment: I thought about this and it would certainly improve the overall performance. I doesn't, however, solve the problem with ENV, EXPOSE, WORKDIR, etc., which is equally bad.

Comment: Do you have unnecessary files in the directory? Like `.git` because it's a git repository. Add that and anything else to `.dockerignore` and you might notice a speed-up.

Comment: I have that already. Build context is 5mb. I have the same Dockerfile just with an ubuntu/trusty base image for x86 and even when it has to start from COPY it finishes the whole build in about 3 seconds total (on a better maschine granted, but still). The hardware difference is i5 + ssd vs. quadcore ARM + micro sd card. I don't think the difference should be orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each instruction of the `Dockerfile` will be run in a container. What it means is that for each instruction it will do the following :

- Instantiate a container from the image created by the previous step, which will create a new layer (the R/W one)
- Do the thing (pip install, etc..)
- Commit, which will copy the top layer as an image layer (I'm pretty sure it is copying the layer)
- And removing the container (if the `--rm` option is specified) (thus, removing the container Read/Write layer)

There are a few I/O operations involved. On an SSD it's really quick, as well as on a good hard drive. When you build it on the Raspberry PI, if you build it on the SD Card (or MicroSD), the performance of the SD card is probably not that good. It will depend on the class of you MicroSD and even then, I don't think it's really good for the card. I made the try with a simple node project, and it definitely took a few minutes instead of a few seconds like it did on my laptop. It is hardware related (mostly I/O for the SD Card, maybe a little bit the CPU, but...).

You might wanna try to use an external hard drive connected to the raspberry Pi and move the docker folders there, to see if the performance are better.

Comment: This confirms my suspicion. An external harddrive would help if you can specify where docker stores containers and images. The default is `/var/lib/docker/`. I moved constant commands like ENV, EXPOSE and VOLUME before COPY, so at least they are cached most of the time, which makes it acceptable.

Comment: Yep. The way I did that on one of my machine was to disable docker temporarly (and be sure nothing is accessing the ``/var/lib/docker`` folder), moving this folder away on an external drive (or in my case an other partition) and do a bind mount or a mount (specified in ``/etc/fstab``.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but for reference, you may have been suffering from the chosen storage driver.

On Ubuntu/Debian, Docker uses by default an AUFS storage driver, which is quite fast.
On other distributions, Docker uses by default a devicemapper storage driver, which is very slow with the default configuration (due to a "loop-lvm" mode, configured by default, and not recommandent for production use).

Check this guide for reference and to see how to configure the devicemapper storage driver in production (without loop mode) : https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/

Answer (score 1):

Another consideration that was not mentioned here, is that on armv7, most packages that you may want to install with pip or apt-get, are not packaged as binaries.

That means that on an amd64 architecture, pip install downloads a binary and it just merely copies it in the right place, but on armv7, it won't find a suitable binary and will instead downloads the source code and will need to build it from scratch.

When you have a package with lots of dependencies, and they need to be built from source, it takes a looong time.

You can check on what is going on during docker build using the `-v` flag on pip

`pip install -v -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

On Arm/v7 arch, some python libs are not ready yet as a binary, building time is so long, as you are building libs for armV7 as well .